# Not unique table/alias Join Query

Tags: mysql, join

I keep getting Not unique table/alias: 'Donut_Order' error in sqlfiddle
I've googled and looked at many of the same issues here on stackoverflow and realize it has something to do with aliases but I can't wrap my head around it.  Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
SELECT date_of_order, Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_order_id, Customer.customer_id,
first_name, last_name, street_address, apt_number, city, st, zip_code, home_phone, mobile_phone, other_phone,
qty_of_donuts, Donut.donut_id,
name, description, unit_price,
unit_price * qty_of_donuts AS line_total,
sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) AS sub_total,
tax, sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) * 1.1 AS total, 
handling_notes
FROM 
Customer JOIN Donut_Order
ON Customer.customer_id = Donut_Order.customer_id,
Donut_Order JOIN Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order
ON Donut_Order.donut_order_id = Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_order_id,
Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order JOIN Donut
ON Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_id = Donut.donut_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, try this:

```
SELECT date_of_order, qodio.donut_order_id, c.customer_id, first_name, last_name, street_address, apt_number, city, st, zip_code, home_phone, mobile_phone, other_phone, qty_of_donuts, d.donut_id, name, description, unit_price, unit_price * qty_of_donuts AS line_total, sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) AS sub_total, tax, sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) * 1.1 AS total, handling_notes
FROM Customer c 
JOIN Donut_Order do ON c.customer_id = do.customer_id
JOIN Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order qodio ON do.donut_order_id = qodio.donut_order_id
JOIN Donut d ON qodio.donut_id = d.donut_id;
```

Comment: Now I return Unknown column 'Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_order_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @jsmarsh I've edited my answer. Try it again. The used table names are now replaced by their aliases.

Comment: This worked for me.  Do you have a decent reference I could read that would make me understand this?

Comment: @jsmarsh For the simplest document (I guess) about aliases here [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp ]. You just need to put aliases when you call a table/column name twice/trice/etc so the query can understand it (like you're putting a unique name). And, I dunno, your joining method is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date_of_order, Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_order_id, Customer.customer_id,
first_name, last_name, street_address, apt_number, city, st, zip_code, home_phone, mobile_phone, other_phone,
qty_of_donuts, Donut.donut_id,
name, description, unit_price,
unit_price * qty_of_donuts AS line_total,
sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) AS sub_total,
tax, sum(unit_price * qty_of_donuts) * 1.1 AS total, 
handling_notes
FROM Customer 
    JOIN Donut_Order ON Customer.customer_id = Donut_Order.customer_id,
    JOIN Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order ON Donut_Order.donut_order_id = Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_order_id,
    JOIN Donut ON Qty_Of_Donuts_In_Order.donut_id = Donut.donut_id;
```